# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'webpushapi'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, web-push

I'm implementing a package called django-webpush in my project
Ref: https://pypi.org/project/django-webpush/

Firstly, I installed this package using the command
`pip install django-webpush`
and it got installed successfully.

Next in my INSTALLED_APPS in Settings.py I included the new application called web push.

When I run `python manage.py runserver` It tells me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 89, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 116, in create
    mod = import_module(mod_path)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'webpushapi'
```

Answer (score 1):

Add 'webpush' instead of 'webpushapi' under `INSTALLED_APPS` in `SETTINGS.py`,

It should be like this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'webpush',
)
```

Then migrate the new added apps.